# How to calculate network mask length for ipv4 address using ipv6 network mask length?

Tags: ipv6, ipv4, subnet

I am trying to calculate ipv4 address in a range using network mask length.
Ex:
Starting IP(v6): ::ffff:1.0.64.0
Network mask length:: 114

How can calculate the ending ip(in v4 format) of this range using the prefix length?
For the above example ips will be in range 1.0.64.0-1.0.127.255
(Calculated this using http://www.gestioip.net/cgi-bin/subnet_calculator.cgi)

Thanks

Vinod

Comment: I am sorry, but it is not very clear what you are asking. Can you show us the code you wrote up to now?

Comment: This is an IPv4 address. Subtract 96 and feed it to your IPv4 code.

Answer (score 2):

Just like with IPv4, you would create an IPv6 mask by setting the first 114 bits to 1 and the remaining bits set to 0, then you would mask the original IPv6 address with that mask using a bitwise `AND` operator to get the subnet ID (and the starting address of the subnet), then OR the inverse of the mask to the subnet ID to get the last address of the subnet.

```
  ::FFFF:1.0.64.0
= 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:0100:4000
= 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111100000001000000000100000000000000

prefix length 114
= 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000
= FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:C000
```

```
    00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111100000001000000000100000000000000
AND 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  = 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111100000001000000000100000000000000

    0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:0100:4000
AND FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:C000
    ---------------------------------------
  = 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:0100:4000

  = ::FFFF:1.0.64.0
```

```
NOT 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  = 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111

NOT FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:C000
    ---------------------------------------
  = 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:3FFF
```

```
    00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111100000001000000000100000000000000
OR  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111111111
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  = 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111100000001000000000111111111111111

    0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:0100:4000
OR  0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:3FFF
    ---------------------------------------
  = 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:0100:7FFF

  = ::FFFF:1.0.127.255
```